# Trying to get the same effect on the right as on the left [css3 ribbons]

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get the same 3d-shadow effect on the right side as the right side.

Please see this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/tdf84nL7/

```
<div class="ribbon">WOW</div>
```

[css]

```
.ribbon {
position:relative;
width: 100%;
height: 30px;
background-color: #5ad2f0;
text-align: left;
border-radius: 5px 0px 0px 5px; 
margin:5px 0;
color:white;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:12px;
padding-left: 20px;   
}
.ribbon:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -10px;
    right:2px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-top: 15px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
    border-right: 16px solid #3aacc9;
    z-index:-1
}
.ribbon:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -14px;
    left:1px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-top: 15px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
    border-right: 16px solid #3aacc9;
    z-index:-1
}
```

The right side doesn't look perfect.

Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.ribbon {
border: 1px solid #000000;
position:relative;
width: 70%;
height: 30px;
background-color: #5ad2f0;
text-align: left;
border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px; 
margin:5px 0;
color:white;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:12px;
padding-left: 20px;   
}
.ribbon:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -14px;
    right:1px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 0; 
 height: 0; 
 border-top: 15px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
 border-left: 16px solid #3aacc9;
    z-index:-1
}
.ribbon:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -14px;
    left:0px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 0; 
 height: 0; 
 border-top: 15px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
 border-right: 16px solid #3aacc9;
    z-index:-1
}
```

```html
  <div class="ribbon">WOW</div>
```

Comment: if I wanted to add a border to it. would it ruin the whole ribbon?

Comment: Added a border. You can't add a border to the ribbon background part. There might be another way. Also, you should try to do it before asking. I usually don't know the answer to your question until I try it.